# How can I read application_name?

Tags: python, postgresql

Can someone show me please, how I can **read** the **application_name** setting 
inside a python trigger ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW application_name;`

Will return the parameter as a column. See [SHOW docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-show.html)

Comment: can I do this with **python** directly ?

Comment: you just use the [plpy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpython-database.html) module. This is how most (all?) interaction is done with the DB in pl/python.